# Parallel Computation for Create_Matrix 'RTextTools' package

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, text-processing, doparallel

I am creating a `DocumentTermMatrix` using `create_matrix()` from [`RTextTools`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RTextTools/index.html) and create `container` and `model` based on that. It is for extremely large datasets.

I do this for each category (factor levels). So for each category it has to run matrix, container and model. When I run the below code in (say 16 core / 64 gb) - it runs only in one core and memory used is less than 10%.

Is there way I can speedup this process? Perhaps using `doparallel` & `foreach`? Any information would certainly help.

```
#import the required libraries
library("RTextTools")
library("hash")
library(tm)

for ( n in 1:length(folderaddress)){
    #Initialize the variables
    traindata = list()
    matrix = list()
    container = list()
    models = list()
    trainingdata = list()
    results = list()
    classifiermodeldiv = 0.80`

    #Create the directory to place the models and the output files
    pradd = paste(combinedmodelsaveaddress[n],"SelftestClassifierModels",sep="")
    if (!file.exists(pradd)){
        dir.create(file.path(pradd))
    }  
    Data$CATEGORY <- as.factor(Data$CATEGORY)

    #Read the training files
    X <- split(Data, Data$CATEGORY)
    data <- lapply(seq_along(X), function(x) as.data.frame(X[[x]])[,5])
    names(data) <- levels(Data$CATEGORY)
    list2env(data, envir = .GlobalEnv)
    files=as.matrix(names(data))
    fileno=length(files)
    fileno=as.integer(fileno)
    print(fileno)

    #For all the files in the training folder(the number of files in the training folder = Number of categories in Taxonomy)
    for(i in 1:fileno){
        filename = as.character(files[i,1])
        data1 = as.data.frame(data[i])
        data1 = as.matrix(data1)
        filenamechanged = gsub ("\\.[[:alnum:]]+","",filename)
        type = matrix(data = as.character(filenamechanged),nrow = length(data1[,1]),ncol=1 )
        data1 = cbind(data1,type)
        traindata[[i]] = data1
        print(i)
    }

    for(i in 1:fileno){
        #Obtain the unique classified data from the train files for one category
        trainingdata1 = as.data.frame(traindata[[i]][,1])
        uniquetraintweet = hash()
        typetrain1 = matrix(data=as.character(traindata[[i]][1,2]), ncol =1, nrow = length(trainingdata1[,1]))

        #If the training data is less than 10 records for a category, do not create a model
        #The model created based on a smaller set of data will not be accurate
        if (length(trainingdata1[,1])<200){
            matrix[[i]] = NULL
            next
        }

        #Obtain the unique classified data from the train files of all the other category except that is considered as training category
        trainingdata2=matrix(data="",nrow=0,ncol=1)

        for (j in 1:fileno){
            if ( j==i) next
            trainingdata2dummy = as.data.frame(traindata[[j]][,1])
            length(trainingdata1[,1])
            colnames(trainingdata2)="feedbacks"
            colnames(trainingdata2dummy)="feedbacks"
            trainingdata2 = rbind(trainingdata2,trainingdata2dummy)

        }

        #Consider one category as training set and make the remaining categories as Others
        typetrain2 = matrix(data="ZZOther",nrow=length(trainingdata2[,1]),ncol=1)
        colnames(trainingdata1)="feedbacks"
        trainingdata[[i]]=rbind(trainingdata1,trainingdata2)
        colnames(typetrain1)="type"
        colnames(typetrain2)="type"
        type=rbind(typetrain1,typetrain2)
        trainingdata[[i]] = cbind(trainingdata[[i]],type)
        trainingdata[[i]]=trainingdata[[i]][sample(nrow(trainingdata[[i]])),]

        #Input the training set and other set to the classifier
        mindoc = max(1,floor(min(0.001*length(trainingdata[[i]][,1]),3)))

        #Create Matrix        
        matrix[[i]] <- create_matrix(trainingdata[[i]][,1], language="english",
                                     removeNumbers=FALSE, stemWords=FALSE,weighting=weightTf,minWordLength=3, minDocFreq=mindoc, maxDocFreq=floor(0.5*(length(trainingdata[[i]][,1]))))
        #rowTotals <- apply(matrix[[i]] , 1, sum) #Find the sum of words in each Document
        #matrix[[i]]   <- matrix[[i]][rowTotals> 0,] 
        print(i)

        #Create Container             
        container[[i]] <- create_container(matrix[[i]],trainingdata[[i]][,2],trainSize=1:length(trainingdata[[i]][,1]),virgin=FALSE)
        print(i)

        #Create Models  
        models[[i]] <- train_models(container[[i]], algorithms=c("SVM"))
        print(i)
    }

    save(matrix, file = paste(pradd,"/Matrix",sep=""))
    save(models, file = paste(pradd,"/Models",sep=""))   
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into parallelization in R? What have you tried so far? You ask if `doParallel` & `foreach` could be used -- have you tried it?

Comment: I am new to foreach and parallelization. I tried it, however i get error in looping through foreach.

Comment: Then it might help others help you to update your question to show your attempt and the error message you receive

Comment: Also, could you share some (sample) data in order to reproduce the computations?

Comment: I wrote a how-to on ['Parallelize a For-Loop by Rewriting it as an Lapply Call'](https://www.jottr.org/2019/01/11/parallelize-a-for-loop-by-rewriting-it-as-an-lapply-call/) that provides some guidance on this topic.  BTW, as I point out in that blog post, `foreach()` is *not* a stand-in replacement for a regular for loop, so it will not help more than `lapply()` and likes will.

Comment: I am Unable to install RTextTools. Error is given Below
  package ‘RTextTools’ is not available (for R version 3.5.3)

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of working with `RTextTools` in parallel. I created the dummy function using information to be found [here](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-1/collingwood-jurka-boydstun-etal.pdf).

The function `myFun` follows the introduction in the above link - at the end it writes a csv file (no directory is specified) containing the analytics/summary. Afterwards it is straight forward application of the `base R` package `parallel` in order to run `myFun` in parallel.

```
library(parallel)
library(RTextTools)
# I. A dummy function
# Uses RTextTools
myFun <- function (trainMethod) {
  library(RTextTools)
  data(USCongress)
  # Create the document-term matrix
  doc_matrix <- create_matrix(USCongress$text, language="english", removeNumbers=TRUE,
                              stemWords=TRUE, removeSparseTerms=.998)
  container <- create_container(doc_matrix, USCongress$major, trainSize=1:4000,
                                testSize=4001:4449, virgin=FALSE)
  # Train
  model <- train_model(container,trainMethod)
  classify <- classify_model(container, model)
  # Analytics
  analytics <- create_analytics(container,
                                cbind(classify))
  summary(analytics)
  # Saving
  nameToSave <- paste(trainMethod, 'DocumentSummary.csv', sep = '_')
  write.csv(analytics@document_summary, nameToSave)
}

# II. Parallel Processing
# 
# 1. Vector for parallelization & number of cores available
trainMethods <- c('SVM','GLMNET','MAXENT','SLDA','BOOSTING')
num_cores <- detectCores() - 1L
# 2. Start a cluster
cl <- makeCluster(num_cores)
# 3. Export Variables needed to the cluster
# specifying exactly which variables should be exported
clusterExport(cl, varlist = c('myFun', 'trainMethods'))
# 4. do in parallel
parLapply(cl, seq_along(trainMethods), function (n) myFun(trainMethod = trainMethods[n]))
# stop the cluster
stopCluster(cl)
```

In your case, you'd have to turn your code into a function `myFun (n, ...)` with `n` being an element of `seq_along(folderaddress)` and of course substitute `seq_along(trainMethods)` for `seq_along(folderaddress)` in `parLapply`.

Of course chances are there exist ways besides parallelization to enhance your code. The problem is without sample data, any suggested improvement is but conjecture.

Comment: This looks correct to me.  Just one comment: please don't use/promote the habit of using `clusterExport(cl, ls())`, because that can be really expensive in real applications and varies across R sessions depending on what has been done before.  Always be explicit what needs to be exported.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Probably should've written something along the lines of `clusterExport(cl, varlist = c('myFun', 'trainMethods'))` .